# Where to get latest stable Mesa?

Tags: drivers, ati, mesa

Atm the only choice we got is between Mesa which ships with Ubuntu (it's outdated before release) or one from Oibag PPA which is latest git development branch (very unstable).

What about latest stable Mesa? There are huge changes in drivers for AMD with each Mesa release, so I wondering how can I get it (atm latest stable is 10.3-RCx) without compiling everything myself (which would propably result in broken system)?

Comment: Same question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/514479/how-do-i-install-the-latest-mesa-release

Answer (score 0):

A [community ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Epaulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa) has been set up for the most recent stable release of mesa, but you will have to be the most recent development version (16.10 as of this post), or the most recent LTS.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa
sudo apt-get update
```