# Battery drains very fast in ubuntu

Tags: battery

As compared to windows battery consumption in Ubuntu is double.

Device - Dell Inspiron 3521

[image]

Comment: You might try [latest kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade) and [latest Mesa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514479/how-do-i-install-the-latest-mesa-release) to see if it'd make any difference.

Comment: There are many battery saving techniques in Ubuntu and Linux in general. Just "google it".

Answer (score 4):

You can check what consumes a lot of power with `powertop` (must be run as root/with sudo). The program has a tab called tunables (switch with <kbd>Tab</kbd>) where you can toggle several settings (Toggle with <kbd>Space</kbd>). Watch the power consumption before and after on the overview tab and check if everything still works as expected. These settings are reset after a reboot.

There is also a utility called `laptop-mode-tools` which automatically switches most tuneables to a powersaving mode when you run on battery.

Both are in the standard repositories, so you can add them with apt:

```
sudo apt-get install powertop laptop-mode-tools
```

Comment: I checked it is showing, all processes are normal.  Windows gives double battery backup than Ubuntu.

Comment: @AlamjitSingh did you try to alter some settings in the tunables tab?