# Atom freezes everything

Tags: 16.04, freeze, atom

I installed Atom to my PC (Ubuntu 16.4) and it keeps on freezing my entire computer.

I have it running on my laptop as well (also 16.4 also x64) but no problems.

But running it on my PC it keeps on freezing the screen. even in safe mode. no mouse action and no keyboard action possible. (audio is still running for a while but stops as well after a few minutes.)

I don't know whats causing it and I don't know how to look those errors up.

If someone needs more hardware information please tell me the command to look it up as well.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall it?

Comment: yes i did reinstall it twice.

Comment: To me it looks like a graphics issue. Please, have a look at `journalctl`, are there any errors for running `atom`?

Comment: how do I know which part belongs to atom?

Comment: Okay, well, just run `journalctl -f` in terminal, and then `atom` alongside, and tell what you see *(if anything)* appearing in the journalctl's output.

Comment: @Hi-Angel you where right. I installed new graphics drivers and it appears to be solved. Post this as you answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That description, specifically reproducible freezes for opening a graphical app *(assuming it doesn't plain take away all available memory)* looks very like graphics driver choking up on GPU lockups or something similar. To be sure you can look at `journalctl`.

If it's the case, try installing [latest mesa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514479/how-do-i-install-the-latest-mesa-release), and [latest kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade), and see if that helps.